# Model is infeasible even though constraints are correct

Tags: python, linear-programming, pulp

I have the following problem I want to solve:

> We have N items with a price and ID, and M categories, where each category
> has a total balance / limit on the sum of prices of items with that category.
> In the end, we want each item to be assigned to ONLY ONE category,
> and each category doesn't exceed its total balance / limit.

Let:

- x<sub>ij</sub> be a binary decision variable where x<sub>ij</sub> = 1 if item i is assigned to category j, and x<sub>ij</sub> = 0 otherwise.
- p<sub>i</sub> be the price of item i.
- c<sub>j</sub> be the price limit of category j.

The constraints are as follows:

1. Each item must be assigned to exactly one category.
2. The total price sum of items assigned to each category must not exceed the category limit.

I have created the linear programming code using PuLP python module:

```py
def assign_items_to_categories(items, categories, category_limits):
    n = len(items)
    m = len(categories)
    model = pulp.LpProblem("Assign_Items_to_Categories")

    # Define decision variables
    x = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("x", ((i, j) for i in range(n) for j in range(m)), cat='Binary')

    # Constraints
    # 1st constraint
    for i in range(n):
        model += pulp.lpSum(x[(i, j)] for j in range(m)) == 1
    
    # 2nd constraint
    for j in range(m):
        model += pulp.lpSum(items[i]["price"] * x[(i, j)] for i in range(n)) <= category_limits[categories[j]]

    # Solve the problem
    model.solve()
    model.writeLP('model.lp')
    # Extract the solution
    assignment_result = {category: [] for category in categories}
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(m):
            if pulp.value(x[(i, j)]) == 1:
                valid = True
                assignment_result[categories[j]].append(items[i])
    return assignment_result

items = [{
            "id": "0892ADA75MH1-00",
            "price": 0.0
        },
        {
            "id": "3WR21137BHJ81",
            "price": 2616023.02
        },
        {
            "id": "3137344ABHEX1",
            "price": 367419.34
        },
         {
            "id": "2312312AAWW31-1",
            "price": 676545.32
        },
        {
            "id": "313243A8WTQV1",
            "price": 228518.29
        }]

categories = ['APPLE', 'META', 'TESLA', 'NETFLIX', 'GOOGLE']
cateogory_limit = 
        {
            "APPLE": 2754707.42,
            "META": 43002.21,
            "TESLA": 240301.31,
            "NETFLIX": 500432.54,
            "GOOGLE": 3100233.41,
        },
```

However, the result always indicated that the problem is infeasible. I believe that the constraint I coded reflected to the constraint that was mentioned in the instructions. Any suggestions to improve this code will be very helpful!

Edit: I have added some sample data for better reference.

Comment: @Reinderien is exactly correct.  Add some data to this with a dictionary or such if you want help.  On your own, try with a *small* set of data, like 2 items and 2 categories that you can solve w/ pencil & paper.  build up from there.  You also don't appear to have an objective for the model.

Comment: @Reinderien, I have added some sample data. Thank you for letting me know!

Comment: @AirSquid, yes I don't have an objective model because this problem is not focused on minimizing nor maximizing. I just want to have all items assigned to one category while not going over any categories' limit. Would it be better to have one though?

Comment: "better" is a business decision. Does it truly not matter which solution is chosen? Or is a solution preferable if it has a more even balance of prices, or a subset of categories that are maximally packed, or something else?

Comment: Now that you mentioned it, yes, I think it's better if the categories have an even balance of prices, if possible.

Comment: Even proportionate to their limit, or even across the board?

Comment: Across the board

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One crude but fast objective minimizing difference between category allocations is to minimize the maximum category subtotal. For very few items it doesn't work very well; for many items it works fine:

```py
import pandas as pd
import pulp


def assign_items_to_categories(
    item_prices: pd.Series,
    cat_limits: pd.Series,
):
    model = pulp.LpProblem(name="Assign_Items_to_Categories", sense=pulp.LpMinimize)

    assign = pd.DataFrame(
        data=pulp.LpVariable.matrix(
            name='assign', cat=pulp.LpBinary,
            indices=(cat_limits.index, item_prices.index),
        ),
        index=cat_limits.index,
        columns=item_prices.index,
    )
    tmax = pulp.LpVariable(name='tmax', cat=pulp.LpContinuous)

    # Each item must be assigned to exactly one category.
    for item, row in assign.items():
        model.addConstraint(
            name=f'excl_{item}',
            constraint=pulp.lpSum(row) == 1,
        )

    subtotals = assign @ item_prices

    for cat, subtotal in subtotals.items():
        # The total price sum of items assigned to each category must not exceed the category limit.
        model.addConstraint(
            name=f'limit_{cat}', constraint=subtotal <= cat_limits[cat])
        model.addConstraint(
            name=f'tmax_{cat}', constraint=subtotal <= tmax)

    model.setObjective(tmax)
    model.solve()
    if model.status != pulp.LpStatusOptimal:
        raise ValueError(model.status)

    assign = assign.map(pulp.value)
    subtotals = subtotals.apply(pulp.value)
    return assign, subtotals


def main() -> None:
    prices = pd.Series(
        index=pd.Index(
            name='item',
            data=('0892ADA75MH1-00', '3WR21137BHJ81', '3137344ABHEX1',
                  '2312312AAWW31-1', '313243A8WTQV1'),
        ),
        name='price',
        data=(0.0, 2_616_023.02, 367_419.34, 676_545.32, 228_518.29),
    )

    cat_limits = pd.Series(
        index=pd.Index(
            name='category',
            data=('APPLE', 'META', 'TESLA', 'NETFLIX', 'GOOGLE'),
        ),
        data=(2_754_707.42, 43_002.21, 240_301.31, 500_432.54, 3_100_233.41),
    )

    assign, subtotals = assign_items_to_categories(item_prices=prices, cat_limits=cat_limits)
    print(subtotals)
    print(assign.T)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

```
Result - Optimal solution found

Objective value:                2616023.02000000
Enumerated nodes:               0
Total iterations:               0
Time (CPU seconds):             0.02
Time (Wallclock seconds):       0.02

Option for printingOptions changed from normal to all
Total time (CPU seconds):       0.02   (Wallclock seconds):       0.02

category
APPLE       676545.32
META             0.00
TESLA       228518.29
NETFLIX     367419.34
GOOGLE     2616023.02
dtype: float64
category         APPLE  META  TESLA  NETFLIX  GOOGLE
item                                                
0892ADA75MH1-00    0.0   0.0    1.0      0.0     0.0
3WR21137BHJ81      0.0   0.0    0.0      0.0     1.0
3137344ABHEX1      0.0   0.0    0.0      1.0     0.0
2312312AAWW31-1    1.0   0.0    0.0      0.0     0.0
313243A8WTQV1      0.0   0.0    1.0      0.0     0.0
```

Comment: thanks for your solution. I tried it with 173 total rows of items, and they said that the problem was infeasible. Do you reckon I should do batches of items per model solve instead? Or would that not work?

Comment: If the problem is genuinely infeasible, batching will not save you. The most it will do is narrow down the part of the data that produce the infeasibility.

Comment: I see, well thank you for helping me until now!

Comment: @ChristopherBryan More specifically, if you are able to reduce items into smaller batches and put them into one round each of optimization where the constraints remain the same, the probability of feasibility is higher (but it would be up to you to determine whether this makes business sense), and there are no guarantees if there is one item with a massive price that does not fit any category.